# I need help getting my sim card to work in a sim7080G device, not all cards work

Tags: iot, at-command, raspberry-pi-pico

I am playing with the waveshare pico-sim-7080g header card. I am in the UK and I can get an O2 4g sim card to work but any other sim cards I try just dont work.

for those who use the card I have included some AT command results:

Signal strength is adequate as AT+CSQ returns 31,99 which as I understand it is not a bad signal

AT+CNACT? returns

+CNACT: 0,0,"0.0.0.0"

+CNACT: 1,0,"0.0.0.0"

+CNACT: 2,0,"0.0.0.0"

+CNACT: 3,0,"0.0.0.0"

which I think means no network

AT+COPS? returns +COPS: 0

When I boot I use AT+CNMP=51 to use both GSM and LTE

Also I also issue AT+CNMB=3 to enable both CAT-M and NB-IoT

when I issue AT+CGNAPN to get the apn list I get +CGNAPN: 0,""

I am stuck at this point as I have tried 4 sim cards and only 1, an o2 on works. SMARTY, Lebara, ThingsMobile all dont connect. I am sure it is me being an idiot that is the problem so I am asking some smart people on the basis I admit I dont know what I dont know :-) Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Are you typing those command via console or you running it through an automatic program? 2) AT+CSQ indicates the signal strength, but it doesn't mean your device has attached to the network, you need to run AT+CEREG? and this could take from anywhere a few seconds to tens of seconds after turning the module on. If you are running a program to blasting out all the command before the network is attached successfully, it will sure failed. All the rest of the commands are meaningless until AT+CEREG confirmed that it has attached to the network.

Comment: 3) SIM7080G is a NB-IoT/CAT-M1 module, if your sim card is not subscribed to NB-IoT/CAT-M1 service, and just a generic LTE sim card, it won't work.